# BASH URL path extraction

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am trying to extract a path from the url with the following expression:

```
url
url+="http://www.google.co.uk/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__REM5I87ZmVOTkq-ipnJx6oisXz0%3D"

url_path=`echo "${url[0]}"| cut -d@ -f2`
echo "$url_path"
```

I would like to get:  `/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__REM5I87ZmVOTkq-ipnJx6oisXz0%3D`

Any ideas please?

Additional challenge comes when the the URLs vary in format for example:

```
url=()
url+="http://www.google.co.uk/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__REM5I87ZmVOTkq-ipnJx6oisXz0%3D"
url+="www.google.co.uk/shopping?hl=en&tab=wf"
url+="https://photos.google.com/?tab=wq"
url+="accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.co.uk"
```

Then result should be:

```
/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__REM5I87ZmVOTkq-ipnJx6oisXz0%3D
/shopping?hl=en&tab=wf
/?tab=wq
/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.co.uk
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: This prints out the hole URL

Comment: Please share the expected result you want

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $url | awk -F / '{print "/"$NF}' 
/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__REM5I87ZmVOTkq-ipnJx6oisXz0%3D
```

Comment: Added your comment in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In straight `bash`, if there are no slashes after `google.co.uk/`, you can use

```
url_path=${url[0]/#*\//\/}
```

The `${<var>/#<pat>/<repl>}` construct replaces `<pat>` at the beginning (`#`) of the expansion of `<var>` with `<repl>`.  Here, that is

```
var => url[0]
pat => *\/ , i.e., anything followed by a slash
repl => \/ , i.e., a single slash
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code specifically is that you are supplying the wrong delimiter to `cut` as well as the wrong field. Instead of `-d@` you should be using `-d'/'`, and in the example you provided you want the 4th field, not the second. So what you should have used was this:

```
url_path=`echo "${url[0]}"| cut -d'/' -f4`
echo $url_path
setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__REM5I87ZmVOTkq-ipnJx6oisXz0%3D
```

However, that omits the beginning slash. If you need that, you can manually prepend it like this:

```
url_path='/'`echo "${url[0]}"| cut -d'/' -f4`
echo $url_path
/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__REM5I87ZmVOTkq-ipnJx6oisXz0%3D
```

If there is a chance the urls will have differing numbers of slashes though, you may need a more robust solution. If you're certain you always want the 4th field, this `cut` example will work fine. If you always want the *last* field, you will be better off with `awk` or with `bash`'s parameter expansion.

Here's what you'd need for either of those:

With `awk`, the delimiter is set with `-F-`, and `$NF` accesses the final field:

```
url_path=`echo ${url[0]} | awk -F / '{print "/"$NF}'`
```

With `bash` parameter expansion, `${var/pattern/}` removes `pattern` from `var`. The pattern `http:\/\/*\/` matches everything from "http://" to the final slash. Once again, the final slash is not in the output and is manually prepended:

```
url_path=`echo "/${url/http:\/\/*\//}"`
```